# React test library: Use findAll in react-test-renderer to find element by classname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I was wondering if there is a solution to use React test renderer to find elements by classname. I found one way to do this but I also would like to know other solutions.

```
const component = create(<Footer/>)
```

As an example we have a footer component and we like to find the links there by classname.

```
component.root.findAll(/* here the class name */)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is using this function:

```
function testSelector(selector = ''): (instance: ReactTestInstance) => boolean {
    const [type, ...classNames] = selector.split('.');
    return instance => {
        if (type && instance.type !== type) {
            return false;
        }
        const {className = ''} = instance.props;
        const instanceClassNames = (className as string).split(' ');
        return classNames.every(className => instanceClassNames.includes(className));
    };
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
expect(component.root.findAll(testSelector('span.footer_link')).length).toBe(2)
```

P.S.
This is not my code, just found it.